# Authenticated proxy in Windows command prompt

Tags: windows, proxy, command-line, authentication

My Internet access is delivered through an authenticated proxy. This is setup correctly in the "Internet Options" control panel applet and all browsing/GUI apps work fine.

For cmd, proxy settings are typically set by exporting `http_proxy`. The applications I'm trying to use are `git` and Putty's `pscp.exe`. I've tried the following syntax to no avail:

```
 set http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.com:port/
```

I've also experimented with [Netsh.exe and ProxyCfg.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384069(v=vs.85).aspx) with no luck.

How does one configure an authenticated proxy in the Windows command prompt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It completely depends on the program you are trying to use - in this case, `pscp`. (`cmd` itself *does not have* any proxy settings - it doesn't make any connections, only executes commands.)

`pscp` is part of PuTTY, so it uses the same settings, which you can configure in PuTTY's GUI:

- Start PuTTY.
- In the configuration window, click *Connection* → *Proxy*, pick *HTTP*, configure the rest.
- Go back to *Session*, select *Default Settings*, and click *Save*.
- `pscp` should now use the proxy.

---

I don't know what protocol are you trying to use with Git -- if it's SSH, using `user@host:path` or `ssh://`, then it depends on the value of `%GIT_SSH%`. If it is set to `plink`, the above procedure applies.

For `http://`, Git should honor `%http_proxy%`. For `git://`, you'll likely have to play with `%GIT_PROXY_COMMAND%`.

Comment: Perfect! Configuring the default proxy settings in `putty` and setting `%GIT_SSH%` to `plink` solved it. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a windows-native way to do this in the `CMD` ?